# Working of == in the Comparable interface used in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, comparable

### Working of == operator in Comparable Interface

**Employee.java**

```
class Employee implements Comparable
{
    int id; String name; int age;

    Employee(int id,String name,int age)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Employee emp = (Employee)obj;
        if(age==emp.age)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        //else if(age>emp.age)
        //return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

---

**display_logic.java**

```
import java.util.*;
class display_logic
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
     al.add(new Employee(1,"Supreeth",21));
     al.add(new Employee(2,"Vijay",31));
     al.add(new Employee(3,"Ganesh",21));
     al.add(new Employee(4,"Aisu",31));
     al.add(new Employee(5,"Aizzz",41));
     Collections.sort(al);
     Iterator it = al.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext())
     {
        Employee emp = (Employee)it.next();
        System.out.println("Employee name" +emp.name+ "," +emp.age);
     }
  }

}
```

### Please let me how does == operator work

- Im not able to get the logic that is being implemented in the output

**Output**

```
Employee name   Aizzz,41
Employee name    Aisu,31
Employee name    Ganesh,21
Employee name    Vijay,31
Employee name    Supreeth,21
```

*Thank You In Advance*

Comment: while sorting if **compareTo()** will **return 1** then next element will be added after previous element , if it **returns -1** element will be added before previous element and if 0 then it depends after or before. **== operator** is simply **comparing values for primitive type** and return **boolean result**.

Comment: You are saying that all employees are less than all other employees, except for themselves. That is, Aizzz < Aisu, but also Aisu < Aizzz. Given this, it's actually impossible to sort them properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contract of `compareTo` says:

> The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all x and y.

So, when using it like this:

```
Employee emp = (Employee)obj;
if(age==emp.age)
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
```

it **doesn't work at all**, because you may have both

```
emp1.compareTo(emp2) == -1      // "emp1 should come before emp2"
```

and

```
emp2.compareTo(emp1) == -1      // "emp2 should come before emp1"
```

which is a violation of the contract. This means that "all bets are off" and any method taking advantage of `compareTo` (such as `Collections.sort`) has undefined behavior.

You **can** use `==` but you'll have to take better care of the `!=` case:

```
Employee emp = (Employee)obj;
if(age==emp.age)
    return 0;
else if (age < emp.age)
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
```

A better way however is to do

```
return Integer.compare(age, emp.age);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply aioobe. But what im looking for is :  If we see the output  The output is  printed in the reverse order. It would be great if you could tell the  logic behind this

Comment: As I mentioned, your compareTo implementation may tell `Collections.sort` that `a < b` *and* `b < a`, so `Collections.sort` can't make ins or outs of how to order the elements, and as a result, you can get strange output like this.

Comment: You can also either flip the comparison, return 1 when age > emp.age and -1 when age < emp.age. Or you can use Collections.reverse(List).